# Using TestNG, is there a way to ignore @before class when calling one class into another?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I have two test classes each containing a number of tests. I'd like to run both of these together without having to have the @BeforeClass setup method being ran both times. I am calling the classes like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { TestClass1.class, TestClass2.class });
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();
    }
```

The reason for this is because I have both of them calling in a pop up menu and only want to select the option one time. If this is unclear I will try to further explain.

I have a collection of individual tests across 5 classes. I want each class to be able to run separately, but I also want to make them run collectively should I desire. In the @BeforeClass I have each of them calling another class that will select what URL I want to use (I am testing with TestNG and using Selenium WebDriver).
When this code runs it will execute the @BeforeClass in each class I list, and I would like to, if possible, ignore the @BeforeClass in all the tests if I execute the tests using the code above.

Comment: Could you please explain further what you want to achieve exactly. It is unclear what the ultimate goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend passing a transformer in to your TestNG test case that implements, `IAnnotationTransformer2`.  That transformer can allow you to control the behavior of the non `@Test` Annotations at runtime.

[IAnnotationTransformer2](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IAnnotationTransformer2.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a @BeforeTest in a common class of your 2 test classes.

Answer (score -1):

I understand you want to run the stuff inside `@Before` only once for your 2 test classes that will be executed at same time together.

If you are using `maven` + `junit 4.x`, there is an option for setup things before and after test suit start and complete.

Or you can simply create a `@ClassRule` at suite level, please see the [doc](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/ClassRule.html)